# In React JS update value of a input field using button & keyboard

Tags: reactjs, state

Following is my react code:

```
export default function Counter() {
    const [count, setcount] = useState(0);
    const increase = () => {setcount(count + 1)};
    const decrease = () => {setcount(count - 1)};
    const manual = (event) => {setcount(event.target.value)}

  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={increase} className='bg-green-700 w-12 border-2'>+</button>
            <input onKeyUp={(event) => {manual}} onChange={setcount} value={count} className='border-2 text-center' type="number" name="count" id="count" />
            <button onClick={decrease} className='bg-rose-700 w-12 border-2'>-</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want the input field to get updated by the buttons as well as manually updating the input field using the keyboard.

Comment: I see your code works fine with buttons when you say manually update, are you referring when arrow buttons on keyboard clicked you want input box value to update? please add more details to questions (detailed explanation on expected output) which would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass parenthesis to your function:

```js
<input onKeyUp={(event) => manual(event)} onChange={setcount} value={count} className='border-2 text-center' type="number" name="count" id="count" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently if your looking to increment the count value every onKeyUp you can get the event listener by using **window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress)** on useEffect and later useCallback to handle setCount .

```js
const [count, setcount] = useState(0);
  const increase = () => {
    setcount(count + 1);
  };
  const decrease = () => {
    setcount(count - 1);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      setcount(count + 1);
    },
    [count]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, [handleKeyPress]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={increase} className="bg-green-700 w-12 border-2">
          +
        </button>
        <input
          onChange={setcount}
          value={count}
          className="border-2 text-center"
          type="number"
          name="count"
          id="count"
        />
        <button onClick={decrease} className="bg-rose-700 w-12 border-2">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```